# is there a way to call polymophism reflection in C++ like my code?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

in C++, i have the class `Base` as a interface class and 2 inheritance class: `Base1` and `Base2` from `Base` class like this:

```
class Base{
    public:
        virtual void printSomething() = 0;
    // Some bla bla code...
};

class Base1 : public Base{
    public:
        Base1();
        void printSomething(); 
};


class Base2 : public Base{
    public:
        Base2();
        void printSomething(); 
};
```

In normal way, in my main.cpp, i have to include following code:

```
Base *b;
string base_name = "Base1"; // or "Base2" 
if(base_name.compare("Base1") == 0){
     b = new Base1();
}else{
     b = new Base2();
}
```

So, i want to using  `Base *b = base_name()` instead of `if()else()` block above. In c++, is this possible, anh how? thanks!

Comment: you could create a factory, but that condition has to be somewhere right?.....

Comment: At some point or the other you need to have the comparison either through if else / switch / better using std::map. Using std::map is better option.

Comment: maybe i will try to use factory, but i don't like this method very much!

Comment: Any time you want conditions based on a run time variable (as opposed to a compile time constant) you're going to end up with run time condition statements (if-else, switch, etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike Java, C++ does not offer native support of the [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) concept. You can write a simple function to construct the specific `Base` instance. This is called a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
Base* create_base_instance(string name) {
  if (name == "Base1")
    return new Base1();
  if (name == "Base2")
    return new Base2();
  throw runtime_error("unknown class name");
}

Base *b;
string base_name = "Base1"; // or "Base2" 
b = create_base_instance(base_name);
```

Comment: I don't like Factory, but there's seem no other answer! :( Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. The long answer is: If you want an idiomatic solution, look up the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) design pattern.

Another approach: You could keep proxy objects keyed in by strings in a map and use that map to create these proxy objects (and clone them when required). This method hides the comparison from the end-user and pushes it deep within the standard library container.

Answer (score 1):

Using std::map to implement the factory pattern.

```
template<typename T>
struct Factory
{
    static Base* Create()
    {
        return new T();
    }
};

typedef std::map<std::string, Base* (*)()> FunMap;
FunMap fun;

void Register()
{
    fun.insert(std::pair<std::string, Base*(*)()>("Derived1", Factory<Derived1>::Create));
    fun.insert(std::pair<std::string, Base*(*)()>("Derived2", Factory<Derived2>::Create));
}


void CreateTypeDemo2(const std::string& name)
{
    Base* bp = fun[name]();
    bp->Name();
}
```

From main, you can call the function this way.

```
Register();
CreateTypeDemo2("Derived1");
CreateTypeDemo2("Derived2");
```

You can even do it as shown below. In the method `CreateDerived2`, you can have different  implemention of creating Derived2() instead of default implementation
Factory::Create  gives us.

```
Base* CreateDerived2()
{
    return new Derived2();
}

void Register()
{
    fun.insert(std::pair<std::string, Base*(*)()>("Derived1",Factory<Derived1>::Create));
    fun.insert(std::pair<std::string, Base*(*)()>("Derived2",CreateDerived2));
}
```

Hope this helps.